# request.FILES.get is empty in a Django project

Tags: python, django, xml, django-views, python-requests

For a project I would like to use two files loaded by the user via two inputs, to apply an external script.

My problem is that I get an error because Django doesn’t seem to be able to locate these inputs. So I have an empty object instead of the file.

Here are my codes:

*home.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <form action="/external/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Input xlsx file :<br><br>
        <input type="file" name="file1" accept=".xml" required><br>
        <input type="file" name="file2" accept=".xml" required><br>
 
        <input type="submit" value="Valider"><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .scripts.extScript import *
 
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
 
def external(request):
 
    f1=request.FILES.get('file1')
    f2=request.FILES.get('file2')
 
    extScript(f1,f2)
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from .views import *
 
urlpatterns=[
    path('',home,name="home"),
    path('external/',external, name="external")
]
```

*architecture:*

```
DjangoProject
   |
    -views.py
    -urls.py
    -scripts
        |
         -extScript.py  

templates
        |
         -home.html
```

and the error specifies that f1 type is < NoneType >

I want to point out that I tried to put f1=request.FILES[‘file1’] and it sends me that ‘file1’ is not found : raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key).

If anyone has an idea, I can’t solve this problem, I feel that everything is fine. Besides, I performed the same kind of function on another project and that works perfectly so I don’t know.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output when you print `request.content_type`, `request.method` and `request.POST`?

Comment: thanks for your answer, so in the same order i get :
(1) application/x-www-form-urlencoded,                 (2) POST,              (3)<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['TiAniuPsiZDyLZaFi8x46lqc0F3RsL2ejBKaNS5GhtlHgTGhgzgEg3IdYox'], 'file1': ['monfichier1.xml'], 'file2': ['monfichier2.xml']}>

Comment: The `content_type` is not right, it should be multipart/form-data. Having `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag should set this, do you have any JS interfering with the form submission?

Comment: OK a get it, damn i'm sorry i just did a typing error in the enctype. thanks again for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are sending files with "POST" Request, which you should listen to on your views because first it start with GET view which don't have files.
So the code must be like the following:

```
def external(request):
    if request.POST:
        f1=request.FILES.get('file1')
        f2=request.FILES.get('file2')
 
        extScript(f1,f2)
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried but it doesn't work, f1 is still None. 
I think that as long as i'm linking the action of the form to a specific function in the views, it can't work without a POST request. The request call the function if i understand well, so no need to check again the request in the function.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who face same issue like this (also same problem like I faced before), following is the solution that works for me.

Let say you have at least this file structure in you Django project directory:

```
djangoproject
-- yourapp
   -- urls.py
   -- views.py
-- templates
   -- home.html
```

Thus, in your template (home.html), put this form part like this:

```
<html>
...
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="fileobs1" accept=".xml, .csv" id="id_fileobs1">
    <input type="file" name="fileobs2" accept=".xml, .csv" id="id_fileobs2">
    <input type="submit" value="Execute">
</form>
...
</html>
```

Explanation: do not forget to put **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form tag. In the input tag, you can add **accept=".xml,.csv"** just to limit the file extension that relate with your purpose.

Then, in your views.py, put this part like this (or similar like this):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def compare(file1, file2):
    print ('compare: ', file1, file2)

def file_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file1 = request.FILES.get('fileobs1')
        file2 = request.FILES.get('fileobs2')
        compare(file1, file2)

    return render(request, "home.html")
```

Explanation: The function *compare* is just example of your external function. The function *file_upload* also works if you don't want to check POST method.

Note: This solution works well in Django 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know, but maybe you need to change the submit to a button `<button type="submit">Upload</button>` instead of `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

When you send request from client, you need to send POST request if file it's the case.